Locally compact groupoid with a Haar system such that the range map restricted to isotropy groupoid is open
Can somebody provide an example of a locally compact groupoid $G$ with a Haar system such that the range map restricted to isotropy groupoid of $G$ is open?
I could not find any specific example for that. I just want to clarify whether the action groupoid $G= H\ltimes X$ where $H$ is a locally compact group and $X$ a locally compact space is an example for this.

What is a Haar system?

Presumably you want to eliminate silly cases like when the isotropy subgroupoid is open eg for discrete groupoids or groupoids with only isotropy

@LSpice, Haar systems are the groupoid analogues of Haar measure.  They are not automatic and when they exist the range map is open

@LSpice a suitably invariant family of measures on the source fibres $s^{-1}(x)$ (say) of a suitable topological groupoid (for all $x$ in the space of objects), or more generally something like a groupoid internal to measurable spaces.

In the case of the groupoid G=H⋉X, if the action is free (H⋉X is a principal groupoid), then the range map restricted to isotropy groupoid is open. In general it is not true.

Welcome to MO, Prof Buneci!
